# Proper way to set the unit and integration tests to python based azure functions in azure devops

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am new to the CI/CD pipelines and trying to implement the end to end automation of Azure Functions in Python . I couldn't find a way to include the unit test code to run in the Yaml file of CI part.

I am using the yaml file provided in the

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops#python

I have written following file to run the test.

```
import azure.functions as func
from . import main


class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_function(self):
        # Construct a mock HTTP request.
        req = func.HttpRequest(
            method='GET',
            body=None,
            url='/api/http_trigger',
            params={'inc': 'hello'})

        # Call the function.
        resp = main(req)

        # Check the output.
        self.assertEqual(
            resp.get_body(),
            b"{'inc': 'hello'}" ,
        )
```

Comment: If possible, please check if this document give any helps:http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2018/11/12/run-python-test-with-azure-devops-pipeline/

Comment: There is a task Python Test: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dazfuller.pyunittest-task, which execute your Python 3 unit tests in Visual Studio Team Services and get your test results and coverage information as part of your build.

Comment: sri, did you ever come up with a solution? To me, the [Azure Python Unit Testing docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#unit-testing) (which you got your sample from) are unclear examples.